# Filter array to unique objects by object.property

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I am trying to achieve is filtering of the `objects` array so that I get an array of objects with **unique** actors.

So this is what I currently have:

```js
var objects = [{
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec46234",
      name: "name",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value'
  },
  {
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec12345",
      name: "name2",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value2'
  },
  {
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec46234",
      name: "name",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value3'
  }
];


objects.filter((value, index, self) => {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}).map(ele => {
  console.log(ele.capture);
});
```

The desired outcome is an array which does not consist of the last array element as this actor property matches the first array element.

But as you can see, at the moment it does not filter any of the array elements.

At first I thought that `return self.indexOf(value.value) === index;` would solve this issue, however this returns an empty array.

The expected result is:

```
[{
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec46234",
      name: "name",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value'
  },
  {
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec12345",
      name: "name2",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value2'
  }
];
```

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 I'll update the question to include the expected result.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The objects in your array are all different objects, even if some happen to have properties with the same values. The `.indexOf()` function is comparing references, not property values.

Also, in practice, none of the three objects have identical properties because they all have a different `.capture` value.

Use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of `.indexOf()`, so that you can compare the properties to find matching objects:

```
objects.filter((value, index, self) => {
  return self.findIndex(v => v.actor.name === value.actor.name) === index;
})
```

Here I'm just using the `.actor.name` property, but of course you could compare additional properties if needed.

(Note that `.findIndex()` is an ES6 function, but I assume that's fine given that your code is already using arrow functions. Or you can [polyfill it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill).)

```js
var objects = [{
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec46234",
      name: "name",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value'
  },
  {
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec12345",
      name: "name2",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value2'
  },
  {
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec46234",
      name: "name",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value3'
  }
];


objects.filter((value, index, self) => {
  return self.findIndex(v => v.actor.name === value.actor.name) === index;
}).map(ele => {
  console.log(ele.capture);
});
```

Comment: ahhh excellent - I actually looked at `findIndex()` but admittidly I could not get this to work. In my example, `objects[0] == objects[2]` (unless I copy pasted wrong) - why does  `return self.findIndex(v => v.actor=== value.actor) === index;` not work in this case? Why do we explicitly have to compare names?

Comment: Note that this 100% answers my question, the above comment is just a curiosity,

Comment: You have separate object instances that happen to have the same property values. That is not the same thing as having the same objects. So `===` and `.indexOf()` compare *references*, and `{} === {}` is always `false` even though they *look* the same. And none of your three array elements are identical because they all have different `.capure` values.

Comment: That went over my a little bit, I am going to have to research that some more. Thanks for the great answer, much appreciated.

Comment: I'll try to put it slightly differently: `var x = {name:'Fred'}; var y = {name:'Fred'};` creates two separate objects. When you say `x == y` it is `false`, because `x` and `y` don't refer to the same object in memory, they refer to separate objects that happen to have the same `.name`.

Comment: Now I'm with you!! That makes much more sense - thank you!

Comment: Cool. Extending that last example, if you then say `var z = x`, that creates a new variable `z` that now refers to the same object that `x` refers to, it doesn't create a copy of that object. So then `x == z` will be `true` (same object) but `y == z` will be `false`(different objects that happen to have same name). Don't worry if it is a bit confusing at first, you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: It's much clearer after you referenced memory comparison, just like pointers in c++ (kinda). Thanks for the knowledge dump - love your work!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ***Object Literal*** to filter the unique element as well.

```js
var objects = [{
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec46234",
      name: "name",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value'
  },
  {
    actor: {
      account: null,
      degraded: false,
      mbox: null,
      mbox_sha1sum: "843c56da78f9eb888274d2d4e12ab1d748ec46234",
      name: "name",
      openid: null
    },
    capture: 'value3'
  }
];

const uniqueObjMap = {};
for (const object of objects) {
  uniqueObjMap[object.actor.name] = object;
}

const uniqueObjects = Object.values(uniqueObjMap);
console.log(uniqueObjects)
```