# How to get list of unique objects from list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a list of unique objects based on a specific key.

```
const array = [
  {"name": "Joe", "age": 42},
  {"name": "Donald", "age": 69},
  {"name": "John", "age": 42},
]
```

How can i get a list of unique objects selected from the list assuming i want a list of people with unique ages.

```
const result = [
  {"name": "Joe", "age": 42},
  {"name": "Donald", "age": 69}
]
```

How can this be done in a performant way, is there a better way than iterating through the elements in a foreach and adding it if it does not exist in the resulting array?

Comment: How do you decide which one to keep?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array to unique objects by object.property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245563/filter-array-to-unique-objects-by-object-property) - it's not an exact fit, but it may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to feed the array to a Map where you key them by age. That will eliminate duplicates, only retaining the *last* in the series of duplicates. Then extract the values again from it:

```js
const array = [{"name": "Joe", "age": 42},{"name": "Donald", "age": 69},{"name": "John", "age": 42}];
const uniques = Array.from(new Map(array.map(o => [o.age, o])).values());
console.log(uniques);
```

If you want to retain the *first* of duplicates, then first reverse the array.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to track `seen` values, here using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) passed as a closure and checking for values using its [`.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) method to return a boolean to a [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) call. This will retain the first seen objects.

```js
const array = [
  { "name": "Joe", "age": 42 },
  { "name": "Donald", "age": 69 },
  { "name": "John", "age": 42 },
]

const unique = (seen => array.filter(o => !seen.has(o.age) && seen.add(o.age)))(new Set());

console.log(unique)
```